# Same Join on multiple fields in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a metadata table **CUST** as below in hive

```
Cust_dec       Cust_det
buy            Interested
buy            Cheap
no_buy         Found Cheaper
no_buy         No Interest
no_buy         Other Faults
```

There's another table **Reg_cst_dtls** that needs to be joined with above metadata table multiple times and derive multiple fields as below.

```
item_id     ca_brd_dec     ne_brd_dec     co_brd_dec     ca_dtl             ne_dtl              co_dtl
1012        buy            no_buy         no_buy         Interested         Found Cheaper       Other Faults
5278        buy            buy                           Found Cheaper      
1572        no_buy         buy            buy            No Interest        Cheap               Cheap
6896        no_buy         no_buy         no_buy         Other Faults       Cheap               Found Cheaper
```

Now, for each item_id **Reg_cst_dtls**, I need to see if ca_brd_dec match Cust_dec then ca_dtl should also match Cust_det and a new field ca_resp should be equal to ca_dtl else null.
Similarly, if ne_brd_dec match Cust_dec then ne_dtl should also match Cust_det and ne_resp should be equal to ne_dtl else null
And if co_brd_dec match Cust_dec then co_dtl should also match Cust_det and co_resp should be equal to co_dtl else null. Expected results as below.

```
item_id     ca_brd_dec     ne_brd_dec     co_brd_dec     ca_dtl             ne_dtl              co_dtl              ca_resp         ne_resp             co_resp
1012        buy            no_buy         no_buy         Interested         Found Cheaper       Other Faults        Interested      Found Cheaper       Other Faults
5278        buy            buy                           Found Cheaper      
1572        no_buy         buy            buy            No Interest        Cheap               Cheap               No Interest
6896        no_buy         no_buy         no_buy         Other Faults       Cheap               Found Cheaper       Other Faults    cheap               Found Cheaper
```

Can anyone help with how this can be achieved in Hive ?

Thanks...!

Comment: How many total records are there in Metadata Table.

Comment: @Narsireddy metadata - 47

Comment: @Narsireddy the other table reg_cst_dtls - 1.2 millions

Comment: as Metada is 47 records , It's Better to implement it in UDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below  hive query. If your data is case insensitive try  upper or lower functions. Hive UDF approch is viable here.

```
SELECT item_id,
   ca_brd_dec,
   ne_brd_dec,
   co_brd_dec,
   ca_dtl,
   ne_dtl,
   co_dtl,
   CASE
       WHEN ca_j.cust_loopup IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE ca_dtl
   END AS ca_resp,
   CASE
       WHEN ne_j.cust_loopup IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE ne_dtl
   END AS ne_resp,
   CASE
       WHEN co_j.cust_loopup IS NULL THEN NULL
       ELSE co_dtl
   END AS co_resp
FROM
  (SELECT item_id,
          ca_brd_dec,
          ne_brd_dec,
          co_brd_dec,
          ca_dtl,
          ne_dtl,
          co_dtl,
          concat(ca_brd_dec, ca_dtl) AS ca,
          concat(ne_brd_dec, ne_dtl) AS ne,
          concat(co_brd_dec, co_dtl) AS co
   FROM reg_cst_dtls reg
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT concat(cust_dec, cust_det) AS cust_loopup
      FROM cust) ca_j ON reg.ca = ca_j.cust_loopup
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT concat(cust_dec, cust_det) AS cust_loopup
      FROM cust) ne_j ON reg.ne = ne_j.cust_loopup
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT concat(cust_dec, cust_det) AS cust_loopup
      FROM cust) co_j ON reg.co = co_j.cust_loopup) sub
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without using multiple joins on same table??

Comment: It's just 47 records , so it might not be costly join. is this query working for you ?

Comment: Oh this is some sample data for dev and in realtime I have a metadata table with ~30 records but the other table Reg_cst_dtls is a huge one with ~1.8 Million records in it and I see it's turning out to be a costly operation with multiple joins. Otherwise query works it's just that Im looking for more optimal way if any.